# Set gui's font in win7

Tags: font

For debian9, the setting in .vimrc take effect for gvim.

```
set guifont=Bitstream\ Vera\ Sans\ Mono\ 14
```

For win7,the setting in _vimrc take no effect for gvim at all.
I open gvim in my win7,

```
:set guifont?
```

The result is `Bitstream Vera Sans Mono`,but i find that the character inputed in my gvim in win7 is not `Bitstream Vera Sans Mono`,why?
How to set gui's font in win7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: `:help guifont`:

> [...]
>
> The font name depends on the GUI used.
>
> [...]
>
> For the Win32 GUI
>
> - takes these options in the font name:>
>
>   - hXX - height is XX (points, can be floating-point)
>   - wXX - width is XX (points, can be floating-point)
>   - b   - bold
>   - i   - italic
>   - u   - underline
>   - s   - strikeout
>   - cXX - character set XX.  Valid charsets are: ANSI, ARABIC,
>           BALTIC, CHINESEBIG5, DEFAULT, EASTEUROPE, GB2312, GREEK,
>           HANGEUL, HEBREW, JOHAB, MAC, OEM, RUSSIAN, SHIFTJIS,
>           SYMBOL, THAI, TURKISH, VIETNAMESE ANSI and BALTIC.
>           Normally you would use "cDEFAULT".
>
>   Use a ':' to separate the options.
> - A '_' can be used in the place of a space, so you don't need to use
>     backslashes to escape the spaces.
> - Examples:
>
>   ```
>   :set guifont=courier_new:h12:w5:b:cRUSSIAN
>   :set guifont=Andale_Mono:h7.5:w4.5
>   ```

Try this:

```
set guifont=Bitstream_Vera_Sans_Mono:h14
```

Note also:

> For Win32, GTK, Motif, Mac OS and Photon:
>
> ```
>  :set guifont=*
> ```
>
> will bring up a font requester, where you can pick the font you want.

After doing so, you can check the output of `:set guifont?` again to see the correct format.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the right command. You need to install the font in a way that is recognized by Windows itself and you need to specify the correct name. See `:help guifont` for the naming conventions.

Also, you can see all available fonts with `:set guifont=*`. This will open a standard font-chooser dialog.